# Drop down menu not working when adding another image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is apart of a theme for a Tumblr account and whenever I add an image here suddenly the drop down menu stops working? If I add another it completely messes up my whole navigation? I don't know what other code I may need to include as there is a lot.

```
{/block:IfNotImageDropdownCategory5URL}
        <div class="image-dd-links">
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat5Link1Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 5 link 1 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 3 link 1 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat5Link1Url}
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat5Link2Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 5 link 2 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 5 link 2 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat5Link2Url}
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat5Link3Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 5 link 3 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 5 link 3 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat5Link3Url}
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat5Link4Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 5 link 4 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 5 link 4 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat5Link4Url}
            {block:IfImageDropdownCat5Link5Url}
            <a class="link-validate" href="{text:Image dropdown cat 5 link 5 url}">{text:Image dropdown cat 5 link 5 text}</a>
            {/block:IfImageDropdownCat5Link5Url}
        </div>    
    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Which image you need  to enter? Please add working sample and not working one, thanks.

Comment: this is the not working sample. Image 5 is what messes it up; if there is just 4 images it works

Comment: probably you have no `IfImageDropdownCat5Link5Url`variable within your template and that's break everything.

Comment: okay where would I find that at to add it? This theme has a ton of javascript files and jquery?